# Batch file to delete/remove folders old of xx days

Tags: windows, batch

I need a batch file to delete folders old of 1 day.

The folders contains inside files that will be removed together with the folders

I tryed 3 different code but do not remove the old folders.

Path where are located folders to delete (path have space):

```
D:\Programmi Installati\
```

Example folder names (start with log_)

```
log_1
log_10-12-2019
log_2008-10000
log_222222211111
```

Days old: 1

```
:: Code 1

@echo off
setlocal

set target="D:\Programmi Installati\"
set days=1

for /f "usebackq delims=" %%G in (
'forfiles /p "%target%" /c "cmd /c if /i @isdir == true echo @path" /d -%days% 2^>nul'
) do rd /s /q "%%~G"

pause
endlocal & exit /b


:: Code 2

forfiles /p "D:\Programmi Installati\" /d -1 /c "cmd /c if @isdir==true rd /s /q @path"



:: Code 3

FORFILES /P "D:\Programmi Installati\" /S /C "cmd /c IF @isdir == TRUE rmdir /S @path /Q" -D -1
```

I'm interested a fix of code already indicate or a new code that works.

Comment: There should be some already answered questions of the same type at https://superuser.com/search?q=batch+delete+files+days

Comment: After some days i find a solution that works i add the solution here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution that works

```
@echo off
forfiles /P "D:\Programmi Installati" /M "log_*" /D -1 /C "cmd /c if @isdir==TRUE echo rd /s /q @path"
```

This code remove only folder with "log_" after 1 day.